# 2 jdk on the same machine. Set a specific java version to sonarqube-4.5.7

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I have windows 7 OS, java 1.7 and 1.8. Sonar works with 1.8, but I do not want to change my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable  every time I compile the project with sonar. In a `wrapper.conf` I set `wrapper.java.command=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/java` but it still doesn't work. Also I changed the `settings.xml` in a `.m2` folder putting

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jdk8</id>
            <properties>
                <JAVA_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131</JAVA_HOME>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
......
```

but without success.

Comment: The current SonarQube version is 6.4 and the current LTS is 5.6.6. You're going to have a hard time finding help for versions before that.

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is that, the municipality is using this version and I want to have it on my local pc.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resolve this problem, and for that I've created a .bat file witch executes the commands I need.

```
echo off
title Ejecuta Sonar

SET PROJECT_HOME=C:\Project\Smarthome

cd %PROJECT_HOME%\xxx\
call mvn clean install

setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8"
setx -m JRE_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8"

cd %PROJECT_HOME%\xxx\
call mvn sonar:sonar

setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7"
setx -m JRE_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/). This allows to install from a variety of Java open-source and to automatize the task. First, **install SdkMan** so you can configure what you need:

- You can see the available Java versions with `sdk list java`
- You can install as many version as you want with `sdk install java VERSION`
- You can set a default for the terminal with `sdk default java VERSION`
- And you can change the version with `sdk use java VERSION`